# Run application | app say error

Tags: c#

I try to run my game in my game launcher but it says:

> Memory access violation

Code

```
String name = GetValue(File.ReadAllLines(Co), "lib-name" + DubDown);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path + "\\Games\\" + name + "\\" + GetValue(File.ReadAllLines(Co), "lib-file" + DubDown));
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DsfTu.png 

here is image with error

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = GetValue(File.ReadAllLines(Co), "lib-name" + DubDown);
```

Why are you reading all lines of a file, but the file name shown below is used?

Does the file contain the names of all the files you want to open?? I think you'll need a loop to do that

```
String name....
```

shown above is included in the code below twice when written here

```
... + name +....
```

and here (as the value of name)

```
....GetValue(File.ReadAllLines(Co), "lib-file" + DubDown));
```

Try writing this like this.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path + "\\Games\\" + name);
```

Unfortunately, as noted above, you'll need to iterate through the contents of the file prior to getting the names from inside the file, as your first line of code portrays. Sort of.

I think you should post more of the code for better assistance.